# Java Mutex implement

Tags: java

I'm implementing Mutex in Java, the code shown as below, I don't why the result doesn't match my expect,
as you can see in the result that I shown, it run as unpredictable

```
    enum MutexStatus {
    FREE, BUSY
};

enum FunctionTypes {
    INCREASE, DECREASE
};

class Mutex {
    private MutexStatus mutexStatus;

    public Mutex() {
        mutexStatus = MutexStatus.FREE;
    }

    public void acquire() {
        synchronized (this) {
            while (mutexStatus == MutexStatus.BUSY)
                ;
            mutexStatus = MutexStatus.BUSY;
        }
    }

    public void release() {
        mutexStatus = MutexStatus.FREE;
    }
}

class MyThread extends Thread {
    private static Mutex mutex = new Mutex();
    private static Integer sharedCounter = 0;
    private FunctionTypes funcType;

    public MyThread(String name, FunctionTypes functionType) {
        super.setName(name);
        funcType = functionType;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            mutex.acquire();
            switch (funcType) {
            case INCREASE:
                sharedCounter++;
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " -> "
                        + sharedCounter);
                break;

            case DECREASE:
                sharedCounter--;
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " -> "
                        + sharedCounter);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            mutex.release();
        }
    }

}

public class MutexImplement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MyThread IncreaseThread = new MyThread("Increase thread",
                FunctionTypes.INCREASE);
        IncreaseThread.start();

        MyThread DecreaseThread = new MyThread("Decrease thread",
                FunctionTypes.DECREASE);
        DecreaseThread.start();
    }

}
```

---

### The result is

```
>Increase thread -> 1
>Decrease thread -> 0
>Increase thread -> 1
>Decrease thread -> 0
>Decrease thread -> 1
>Increase thread -> 1
>...........
```

Comment: Maybe it's not the only error in your code, but your `mutexStatus` must definitely be volatile.

Comment: @Danstahr can you give some trick

Comment: See http://jeremymanson.blogspot.cz/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html.

Comment: The acquire() function also isn't thread-safe. For instance : `Thread A passes throug while (mutexStatus == MutexStatus.BUSY)` -> reschedule to Thread B -> `Thread B passes through while (mutexStatus == MutexStatus.BUSY)` -> oops...

Comment: @Danstahr Can you suggest me a solution to solve this problem, thanks for your comment, it very helpfull

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel? Just use a a synchronized block, or a Lock.

Comment: @JBNizet i see, but i want to implement by myself
I modify my code and it run as i expected, but i don't know is it the best solution for this problem
public void acquire() {
        synchronized (this) {
            while (mutexStatus == MutexStatus.BUSY)
                ;
            mutexStatus = MutexStatus.BUSY;
        }
    }

Comment: Implementing a mutex by hand is sort of tricky and as far as I know, it can't be done without the OS support. You need an atomic operation for both reading and setting the variable. Without using the synchronized blocks or other concurrency tools such as in-built locks, it's not possible.

Comment: Before implementing something yourself, you need to grasp the basic principles, and this code shows that you haven't. Read the [concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). Read the book *Java Concurrency in Practice*.

Comment: How about if i modify as the code above, using synchronized ?

Comment: @user872342: No, that's even worse. Don't try random solutions. Read a book.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at 17.4 in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html. The threads will have their own local copy of the variables that they share (or don't actually). As already suggested make your shared variables volatile or use some synchronization/concurrency control. You may also want to take a look at the spin loop (the while loop) and use some signalling.

Now Java has lots of constructs to do this all for you though I suspect you have been asked to create a mutex yourself. For the record try to avoid your own homebrews and try and use the provided concurrency constructs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as you can see my mutex variable is static so it will share with all object

Comment: @user872342: no, that's incorrect. Multiple threads will see a different value of the mutex status, because they execute on different cores, each having a cache of this mutex status. You need to apply proper synchronization to avoid this problem. And it's not the only one you have. Cocurrency is hard. You should use the constructs provided by the language and the standard API instead of reinventing them without understanding what all the issues might be.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet, I has modified my code using synchronized, is it the good solution for this